# Tkinter - modifying buttons based on rows and columns

Tags: python, tkinter, button, colors, grid

I want to change the colour of a button based on its row and column. I am able to search for adjacent buttons, but cant do anything with them. The code is a python version of the board game Othello, and I am trying to get the "sandwiching" aspect of the game to run. Ideally, it stays in the grid system so I am able to code to my ability

```
from tkinter import *

### Function to change button colour ###
def changeColour(tempButton, row, column):
    if tempButton.cget("bg") == "black":
        tempButton.configure (bg = "white")
    else:
        tempButton.configure (bg = "black")
    sandwichButton(tempButton, row, column)

### Function to sandwich adjacent buttons ###
def sandwichButton(originButton, row, column):
    for x in range (-1,2,1):
        for y in range (-1,2,1):
            aRow = (row + y)
            aColumn = (column + x)
            adjacentInfo = find_position(othello, aRow, aColumn)
            endButtonInfo = find_position(othello, aRow + y, aColumn + x)
            if adjacentInfo["row"] == (aRow) and adjacentInfo["column"] == (aColumn):   
                adjacentButton = ADJACENT INFORMATION
                if endButtonInfo["row"] == (aRow + y) and endButtonInfo["column"] == (aColumn+x):
                    if originButton.cget("bg") == "black":
                        adjacentButton.configure (bg = "white")
                    else:
                        adjacentButton.configure (bg = "black")               


### Function to find button position ###
def find_position(frame, row, column):
    for children in frame.children.values():
        info = children.grid_info()
        if info["row"] == row and info["column"] == column:
            return info
            break

### Creating the window ###
othello = Tk()
othello.title("Othello Draft 1")
othello.geometry("800x800")

### Creating buttons ###
for r in range (8): #Rows
    for c in range(8): #Columns
        button = Button(othello, width = 10, height = 5)
        button.grid(row = r, column = c)
        button.configure (bg = "green", command = lambda buttonName = button, r = r, c = c: changeColour(buttonName, r, c))

### Running the window ###
othello.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the buttons to a list and use an if and elif statement to configure the buttons and input your conditions into the if.

```
for button in [list your buttons here]
    if condition:
        button.config(command=command(), bg=colour)
    elif condition:
        button.config(command=command2(), bg=colour2)
```

Comment: The issue I'm having is that I can't do any commands with the adjacent buttons as I don't know how to choose which button I am referencing, only the clicked button. Is it possible to get a button based on it's row or column? Ideally something like this `if button[row + 1].cget("bg") == colour:`

Comment: Iv edited it now but i forgot to add that your buttons can be listed in a list and attributed commands like that, and the conditions can be something like
`if column < number and column > second number: `
So as to allow them to have things attributed to them.